# Vueftify check box sometime renders as weird characters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

We've started using Vuetify but have found that check boxes are occasionally rendering as weird text characters like this:
[image: Weird Characters]

Refreshing the page nearly always fixes the problem but we obviously don't want users to ever see this. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: It will be tough to debug/fix unless there's a reliable way to reproduce, and it may be unique to your specific environment.  Is the problem seen during dev or in production?  Does inspecting the DOM reveal any information as to what's going on when the bug is active? Providing your vuetify and app config may be useful, as well as the checkbox and nearby surrounding code.

Comment: I think this is a problem with the icon font. Are you using the css/font-based icons? Try [switching to the SVG-based icons](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#mdi-js-svg)